# disable all flake8-doc-strings checks

Tags: python, flake8

I'm using [wemake-python-styleguide](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/index.html) linter in a project. I have a project-scoped `setup.cfg` file that looks like this:

```
[flake8]
# Base flake8 configuration:
format = wemake
show-source = True
statistics = True
doctests = False

# Plugins:
min-name-length = 1
max-returns = 2
max-arguments = 4
max-complexity = 6
max-line-length = 80

# Self settings:
max-imports = 16

# Excluding some directories:
exclude =
  .git
  __pycache__
  .venv
  .eggs
  *.egg
  .idea

# Exclude some violation checks globally:
ignore =
    # WPS305: Found `f` string
    WPS305
    # WPS336 Found explicit string concat
    WPS336
    # Q000  Remove bad quotes -> ""
    Q000
    # WPS421 Found wrong function call
    WPS421
```

I'd like to disable *all* checks for doc strings. I know I can use error codes, but the [list](https://www.pydocstyle.org/en/latest/error_codes.html) is long.

Is there a way to turn off a specific `flake8` plugin, in my case, the `flake8-docstrings` plugin?

As far as I'm concenred there is no way to disable it inside the `setup.cfg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can ignore all codes by using a prefix

you currently have an `ignore =` setting, you would add `D` (the code for `flake8-docstrings`) to that

I'd also suggest using `extend-ignore` over `ignore` since that will preserve the default set of ignored things (including some conflicting default rules (W504/W503))

---

disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of flake8 and flake8-docstrings